# Integro-differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, integro-differential-equations

I found the following differential equation:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}f\left(x,t\right)=xf\left(x,t\right)+g\left(x\right)\int_{0}^{1}f\left(x',t\right)x'\mathrm{d}x'$$

to solve for $f(x,t)$. Here $g(x)$ is a given function of $x$, and we know the initial condition $f(x,0)$.

Before I try to solve this equation numerically, anyone knows if there is an analytical solution available?

Comment: It may be interesting to notice that $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}f\left(x,t\right)-xf\left(x,t\right)$ splits as a function of $x$ times a function of $t$.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier Yes, perhaps some form of variable separation can work. But I can't figure it out.